# How do I create an EDI invoce (XRechnung) in odoo 15?

Tags: invoice, odoo-15

We're using odoo 15 an we have to create an invoice in an electronic data interchange (EDI) format (in Germany: "XRechnung (UBL)"). So far, we have created only invoices and printed them as PDF. How do I make odoo 15 ready to create invoices and how do I have to export them as a XRechnung?

The [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/applications/finance/accounting/customer_invoices/electronic_invoicing.html) says the module "account_edi_ubl_cii" for "import/export electronic invoices with UBL/CII" has to be installed, but I can't find it in the search. Likewise, I would have thought that there should be the module "l10n_de_edi" for the German format, but this can't be found via the search either. What exactly do I need to install so that I can export invoices in the format XRechnung? Currently, only "Factur-X (FR)" is available in the advanced settings of the Electronic Invoicing. And where can I download the invoice as XRechnung afterwards?

Comment: Please do some (proper) research: [Google: account_edi_ubl_cii](https://www.google.com/search?q=account_edi_ubl_cii)  ==> [first link: Is Odoo an access point (AP) of Peppol?](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/is-odoo-an-access-point-ap-of-peppol-v14-v15-v16-197474) says (20/06/2022):  `The new module 'account_edi_ubl_cii' ("Import/Export electronic invoices with UBL/CII") has just been merged (14.0/15.0 -> master)`